# SQL Server 2008 data types

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2008, types

What are the different SQL Server 2008 data types?

I am specifically trying to find the equivalent of a long int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 Data Types : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx

Long Int (from VB so 32 Bit / 4 Byte int) is a SQL Int.

Answer (score 1):

[long](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) int range (–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) in sql is [bigint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933198(SQL.80).aspx)(–9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807)